# Pass Latitude Longitude data to google map from another View Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitableview, panel

I am using two view controllers, with floating panel GitHub library. https://github.com/SCENEE/FloatingPanel

`1) MapViewController.`
`2) DataViewController.`

MapViewController contains only google map and google map methods.

DataViewController contains tableview, data model & data source.

On MapViewController I am using floatingPanel which contains DataViewController (tableView).

- Issue:
  How can I pass Latitude & Longitude data to MapViewController to display on google Map. Please suggest.

**Updated with code:**

DataViewController:

```
func loadFriend(withUid: String) {

        let dataLatitude = aFriend.latitude
        let dataLongtitude = aFriend.longitude
            self.delegate?.sendDataToFirstViewController(mapLat: dataLatitude, mapLong: dataLongtitude)


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }
```

Delegate DataViewController:

```
protocol MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol {
    func sendDataToFirstViewController(mapLat: Double, mapLong: Double)
}
```

Class DataViewController:

`var delegate: MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol? = nil`

MapViewController:

`class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate, MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol {`

Delegate call on MapViewController:

```
func sendDataToFirstViewController(mapLat: Double, mapLong: Double) {
        print(mapLat)
        print(mapLong)
    }
```

Comment: in this case best pratice will be delegate for passing data from one VC to another VC. Or you can use block also.

Comment: @chiragshah But both `viewcontroller` loaded at the same time. Not loading properly. But I haven't tried block. any example for both can be possible ? I am using `Firebase data`

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback from DataViewController to MapViewController, after receiving call then update view in MapViewController

Comment: I updated my question with code. posted my delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your request from the comment:

**Delegation approach**

```swift
protocol DataViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func dataViewController(_ dataViewController: DataViewController, coordicatesDidChange coordiates: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}

class DataViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: DataViewControllerDelegate?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let coordiatesForRow = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.11515, longitude: 52.124124)

        self.delegate?.dataViewController(self, coordicatesDidChange: coordiatesForRow)
    }

    // ...
}


class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    let dataViewController = DataViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataViewController.delegate = self
    }

    // ...
}

extension MapViewController: DataViewControllerDelegate {
    func dataViewController(_ dataViewController: DataViewController, coordicatesDidChange coordiates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("New latitude: \(coordiates.latitude), longitude: \(coordiates.longitude)")
    }
}
```

---

**Closure/Block approach**

```swift
class DataViewController: UITableViewController {

    var onCoordinatesChange: ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let coordiatesForRow = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.11515, longitude: 52.124124)

        self.onCoordinatesChange?(coordiatesForRow)
    }

    // ...
}


class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    let dataViewController = DataViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataViewController.onCoordinatesChange = { (coordiates) in
            print("New latitude: \(coordiates.latitude), longitude: \(coordiates.longitude)")
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my delegation method? What I am doing wrong in it? Just updated my question with code

Comment: @Masam Are you setting DataViewController's delegate property in the MapViewController? ex. ``self.dataViewController.delegate = self``? (you can do it for example in `viewDidLoad` or just after DataViewController is initialized)

Comment: giving me error if I use `self.dataViewController.delegate = self` in `MapViewController`. Error : `Value of type 'MapViewController' has no member 'dataViewController' `

Comment: @Masam `dataViewController` was just an example. Replace it with the property name you actually use in your project. (the property of type DataViewController)

Comment: I have implemented your delegate method. But problem is which makes me confuse that in `MapViewController` how the function call.

Comment: @ yes I know I am using my property name.

Comment: its not printing. `print("New latitude: \(coordiates.latitude), longitude: \(coordiates.longitude)") ` . even not coming into function after breakpoint.

Comment: How can I call this function `func dataViewController(_ ... ` 
because it requires arguments/parameter on `MapViewController` `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Sorry @Masam I don't get what the problem is. Please read carefully the examples, try to understand them, because they're pretty self-explanatory. If delegation pattern does not suit you, try using closures (blocks) or go through a tutorial or an article about protocol delegation pattern like this one: https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5

Comment: I implemented block approach, the problem I have identified is `mapViewController` loaded more fast as compared to `dataViewController` and thats why values are `nil` and nothing loaded. because I am not using `didSelect`. I have to display lat long on load.

Comment: MapViewController should be loaded before DataViewController. Juts use `onCoordinatesChange` block when you're sure thath DataViewController's data is ready. `didSelect` method was just an example.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same way. Well here is the link of my project. I have created sample project and try to use Closure/block. Can you please check? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tKLMC_Atlj2JCZmkPyA-Z0TUbxnuooV8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

When you're transitioning from MapViewController to DataViewController
you need to set the delegate,
through a segue or creating an instance of the vc and setting its delegate to self.

then in DataViewController hold a weak instance of DataViewControllerDelegate
and when you want to trigger the delegate method .. just call them using this instance

for example:

```
protocol DataViewControllerDelegate: class {
 func doSomething()
}

class DataViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: DataViewControllerDelegate?

func someOfYourOwnFunction() {

  //trigger the delegate method
  delegate?.doSomething()
}
}
```